# vkFreeMemory memory leaks while the VkDeviceMemory object was allocated with VkExportMemoryAllocateInfo

Tags: windows, vulkan

I am using the VK_KHR_external_memory_win32 extension to share GPU memory with OpenGL on Windows, the shared texture works fine.

The memory was allocated by vkAllocateMemory() with VkMemoryAllocateInfo that the pNext contains a VkExternalMemoryImageCreateInfo structure whose handleTypes is VK_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_HANDLE_TYPE_OPAQUE_WIN32_BIT or VK_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_HANDLE_TYPE_D3D11_IMAGE_BIT_NV for Nvidia cards.

But the memory will not return to the GPU memory heap after the related VkDeviceMemory object was freed by vkFreeMemory().

I have test Intel HD 630 / AMD RX 5700XT / Nvidia 1660 Ti graphics cards, all of them have the memory leaks issue no matter if the dedicated memory is enable or not.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved according to the [vulkan spec](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.html#_win32_external_memory):

> For handle types defined as NT handles, the handles returned by vkGetMemoryWin32HandleKHR are owned by the application and hold a reference to their payload. **To avoid leaking resources, the application must release ownership of them using the CloseHandle system call when they are no longer needed.**